# Why a template alias specialization depends on the context in which it is referred?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, alias, template-aliases

Consider this example code:

```
template <class T>
using pt_type = typename T::type;

template <class T>
class V {
  using type = int;
  public:
  using pt = pt_type<V>;
};

void g() {
  V<int>::pt a; // Does compile
  pt_type<V<int>> b; // Does not compile
}
```

`V<int>::pt` is an alias for `pt_type<V<int>>`. Nevertheless the fact it is defined depends on the context where it is referred.

Where is it explained in the **C++ standard** that the substitution of the template parameter by the template argument is performed in the context where is refered the alias specialization?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nowhere. This is [core issue 1554](https://wg21.link/cwg1554).

> The interaction of alias templates and access control is not clear from the current wording of 14.5.7 [temp.alias]. For example:
>
> ```
> template <class T> using foo = typename T::foo;
>
> class B {
>   typedef int foo;
>   friend struct C;
> };
>
> struct C {
>   foo<B> f;    // Well-formed?
> };
> ```

Answer (score -1):

`using pt_type = typename T::type;` can't access V::type becasue type is private.

The following works:

```
template <class T>
using pt_type = typename T::type;

template<class T>
class V
{
  public:
    using type = int;
    using pt = pt_type<V>;
};

void g()
{
    V<int>::pt a; //Do compile
    pt_type<V<int>> b; //Do not compile
}
```

Comment: Please read the code one more time. pt_type do access V::type in the definition of V::pt.

Answer (score -1):

In V::pt you are accessing to your "own" type and you can do it, but the private makes it impossible in the second case.
So V::pt crates an instanciation of pt_type passing your private type int.
But in the second case you try directly and it does not work,

Comment: OK This is second out of subject answer, I am waiting for a c++ standard quotation

Comment: What standard quotation? That you cannot access private members?

Comment: And you? Make it public and it works. As @Caleb already shown you. This is not context dependant because you are referring to them in different paths. Actually, with GCC 7.2 none of your 2 lines even work. As normal.